# When adding addin extension to project Startup function is never hit with ArcObjects and C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, extensions

I have created an Esri Addin toolbar in VS2010 to add layers and search an address file, this works fine. I want to add an extension that will replace text on a template MXD with the current users details. I have all the logic working in a base class and would like to add an extension that listens for the user to switch to layout view and then calls a function in my base class. I have everything working except that when I right click the project and add an extension the extension code never loads. I am probably missing something pretty basic, could someone please point it out to me.

```
[Guid("ff8f632e-79c3-4168-a591-441bb8f6c2d7")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("DCC_Toolbar_10.addUserDetailsextension")]
public class addUserDetailsextension : IExtension
{
    #region COM Registration Function(s)
    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    [ComVisible(false)]
    static void RegisterFunction(Type registerType)
    {
        // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
        ArcGISCategoryRegistration(registerType);

        //
        // TODO: Add any COM registration code here
        //

    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    [ComVisible(false)]
    static void UnregisterFunction(Type registerType)
    {
        // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
        ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(registerType);

        //
        // TODO: Add any COM unregistration code here
        //
    }

    #region ArcGIS Component Category Registrar generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category registration -
    /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ArcGISCategoryRegistration(Type registerType)
    {
        string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
        MxExtension.Register(regKey);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category unregistration -
    /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(Type registerType)
    {
        string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
        MxExtension.Unregister(regKey);
    }

    #endregion
    #endregion
    private IApplication m_application;

    #region IExtension Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of extension. Do not exceed 31 characters
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            //TODO: Modify string to uniquely identify extension
            return "addUserDetailsextension";
        }
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        //TODO: Clean up resources

        m_application = null;
    }

    public void Startup(ref object initializationData)
    {
        m_application = initializationData as IApplication;
        if (m_application == null)
            return;

        //Listening to document events
        SetUpDocumentEvent(m_application.Document);
    }

    #endregion

     #region Document events
    //Event member variable.
    private ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_Event m_docEvents = null;

    //Wiring.
    private void SetUpDocumentEvent(ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IDocument myDocument)
    {
        m_docEvents = myDocument as ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_Event;
        m_docEvents.NewDocument += new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_NewDocumentEventHandler(OnNewDocument);
        m_docEvents.OpenDocument += new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_OpenDocumentEventHandler(OnOpenDocument);
    }

    //Event handler methods.
    void OnNewDocument()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New document event (C# Sample)");
    }

    void OnOpenDocument()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Open document event (C# Sample)");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was adding the wrong kind of extension.

Correct Way

right click on project -> add -> new item, select ArcGis -> desktop Addins -> Addin Component -> extension.

Wrong Way

right click on project -> add -> new item, select ArcGis -> extending Arc Objects -> application extension. This was not obvious from anything i had read